# illegal use of break statement; javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, break

When this variable becomes a certain amount i want the loop to stop, but i keep getting the error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement".

```
function loop() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        jet1.draw();
        drawAllEnemies();
        requestAnimFrame(loop);
        if (game==1) {

            break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `break` is used to break out of loops. In your code, you have no loops.

Comment: @Hogan It's a self-scheduling function

Comment: First if statement: `if (isPlaying && game != 1)`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) is to break out of a loop like for, while, switch etc which you don't have here, you need to use `return` to break the execution flow of the current function and return to the caller.

```
function loop() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        jet1.draw();
        drawAllEnemies();
        requestAnimFrame(loop);
        if (game == 1) {
           return
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This does not cover the logic behind the if condition or when to return from the method, for that we need to have more context regarding the `drawAllEnemies` and `requestAnimFrame` method as well as how `game` value is updated

Comment: oh, duhh... i'm new to all of this, but thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Doesn't actually exit the loop at all. requestAnimFrame will be called regardless of the value of `game`, causing `loop` to run forever.

Comment: that will depend on how `requestAnimFrame` is implemented and how the callback `loop` is called... if there is an conditional call to the callback it will exit

Comment: `requestAnimFrame` is most likely just an alias for `requestAnimationFrame`. In other words: if you called `loop` once, requestAnimFrame will ensure another call to `loop` will be made, regardless of the value of `game`. The current answer is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure requestAnimFrame stops being called once game == 1. A break statement only exits a traditional loop (e.g. `while()`).

```
function loop() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        jet1.draw();
        drawAllEnemies();
        if (game != 1) {
            requestAnimFrame(loop);
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you could simply skip the second `if` condition and change the first condition to `if (isPlaying && game !== 1)`. You would have to make a variable called game and give it a value of 0. Add 1 to it every game.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function `next()` which will maybe inspire you.

```js
function queue(target) {
        var array = Array.prototype;

        var queueing = [];

        target.queue = queue;
        target.queued = queued;

        return target;

        function queued(action) {
            return function () {
                var self = this;
                var args = arguments;

                queue(function (next) {
                    action.apply(self, array.concat.apply(next, args));
                });
            };
        }

        function queue(action) {
            if (!action) {
                return;
            }

            queueing.push(action);

            if (queueing.length === 1) {
                next();
            }
        }

        function next() {
            queueing[0](function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                queueing = queueing.slice(1);

                if (queueing.length) {
                    next();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that things also,

```
const re =  winState.map(elements => {
    let a = gameState[elements[0]];
    let b = gameState[elements[1]];
    let c = gameState[elements[2]];
```

if you want to quit in this loop simply you

return the whole function

```
if (a === b && b === c) {
         return re;
    }
}
```

when this condition is true you quit this loop

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use **break** statement in forEach loop, you can replace forEach with **for** loop